# Facebook app, OAuth redirect to local virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, facebook-login, facebook-oauth

I've got a virtual machine running on ESXI which I use for local development, I access this machine in my browser via a local domain, http://dev for example. This all works well and no issue for years until I've just started using Facebook Login which requires OAuth redirect URLs to be 'real'.

I can no longer use my http://dev as it won't allow it, I noticed it will however allow http://localhost.

I should note I'm not always using apache/nginx etc so I don't want to be creating virtual hosts

How do I go about being able to register a virtual machine for a OAuth redirect when it's not accessible on localhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite being sure I've tried this before, I did just try the local IP address of the server (`192.168.0.111`) and looks like that worked for the redirect/callback on the Facebook Developers Console.

So, while not ideal, you can use the local IP rather than the hostname.